# UDEV build error - undefined reference to `mq_getattr'

Tags: udev

I am trying to build `udev` package from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/ version `182` with our custom toolchain.

My configure options are:

```
./configure \
    --with-gnu-ld \
    --prefix=%{_toolchain} \
    --sysconfdir=%{_toolchain}/etc \
    --libexecdir=%{_toolchain}/libexec \
    --with-usb-ids-path=no \
    --with-pci-ids-path=no \
    --disable-introspection \
    --disable-keymap
```

During `make` I get the following error:

```
src/udevd-sd-daemon.o: In function `sd_is_mq':
sd-daemon.c:(.text+0xacd): undefined reference to `mq_getattr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [udevd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea about how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `undefined reference` error means you are missing the library in which `mq_getattr` is defined. Googling for `mq_getattr` shows it's a standard Linux function. Reading `man mq_getattr` finds

> Link with `-lrt`.

right at the top. So you must add `-lrt` to your linker options, however you do that in your custom toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Configure with variable LDFLAGS.

```
 LDFLAGS='-lrt' ./configure
```